# How to make JButton clickable in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a program where I have a JTable with text in most cells, however the last cell in each row I need to have a JButton. I am using a custom button renderer as well as editor ( i don't want users editing the content of anything in the table).  I'm unsure as how to get my buttons clickable though. My main code is:

**StartingPoint.java**

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class StartingPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String column_names[] = {"Text", "Button"};
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(column_names, 0);

        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("Button 1");
        button1.setToolTipText("Button");

        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setText("Button 2");
        button2.setToolTipText("Buttonnn");

        Vector<Object> row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add("Testing");
        row1.add(button1);

        Vector<Object> row2 = new Vector<Object>();
        row2.add("More Testing");
        row2.add(button2);

        dtm.addRow(row1);
        dtm.addRow(row2);

        JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
        JScrollPane scrolly = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JTableButtonRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
        JTableButtonEditor buttonEditor = new JTableButtonEditor();
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(buttonEditor);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrolly);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**JTableButtonRenderer**

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    JTableButtonRenderer() {}
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object 
value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rows, int columns) {
        JButton button = (JButton)value;
        return button;
    }
}
```

**JTableButtonEditor.java**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class JTableButtonEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, 
boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Do I need to change something in the renderer / editor classes? I also tried adding actionlistener in my StartingPoint class when I create the button.

Comment: First of all, don't add components to your model, a model carries data or state, the renderer/editor reflects that state in some meaningful way. The question then becomes, what is it that these buttons need to do?  As an editor is "suppose" to return a value back to the model

Comment: I'm going to throw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070511/add-jbutton-to-each-row-of-a-jtable/25071138#25071138) out there, because I have a pathological dislike for buttons in `JTable`s, but, you should also consider having a look at [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for another example

Comment: The button in the end will open a new window, displaying an image given a directory (which will be stored in the buttons tooltip)

Answer (score 2):

"Conceptually", the idea is pretty simple and is covered in some detail in [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

You need to start by defining your editor (and renderer).  I've chosen to wrap both together for simplicity, as much of the functionality is repeated for both.

```
public class TableDeleteButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

    private File source;
    private JButton button;

    public TableDeleteButtonEditor() {
        button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new LoadActionListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    protected JButton prepare(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (!(value instanceof File)) {
            source = null;
            button.setEnabled(false);
            return null;
        }
        source = (File) value;
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText(source.getName());
        button.setToolTipText(source.getPath());
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        return prepare(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                  Object value,
                                  boolean isSelected,
                                  boolean hasFocus,
                                  int row,
                                  int column) {
        return prepare(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }

    public class LoadActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // Here, you need to make some decisions about what to do...
            // You have a reference to the File instance
            System.out.println("You clicked " + source);
            stopCellEditing();
        }

    }
}
```

Since it's likely that you'll only have one active editor, when ever `getTableCellEditorComponent` is called, you need to grab a reference to the underlying data (ie the `File` reference).

Typically, a editor will return a value back to the model, in this case, I'm not sure that makes sense.  Not saying you can't do it, but I'd be questioning the purpose.

For my example, I only needed the reference to the `File` itself, so, technically, I only needed a single column.  Instead, I devised a model which required two columns, but used the reference of the `File` to populate both.  This is a neat example which demonstrates the ability for a "simple" object to be expanded into multiple parts and represented by the model in a different way...

```
public class FileTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<File> files;

    public FileTableModel(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return files.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 1: return File.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        File file = files.get(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0: return file.getName();
            case 1: return file;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, the important parts here are the `isCellEditable` and `getColumnClass` methods.  These help determine which cells can be edited and provide a entry point for looking up renderers/editors for the `JTable`, which brings us to the next step, you need to configure the `JTable` to support your custom editor/renderer

There's a few ways that you can do this, but for simplicity, `setDefaultRenderer` and `setDefaultEditor` should work just fine...

```
List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new File(".").listFiles());
FileTableModel model = new FileTableModel(files);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setDefaultEditor(File.class, new TableDeleteButtonEditor());
table.setDefaultRenderer(File.class, new TableDeleteButtonEditor());
```

*nb: You can use a single instance of `TableDeleteButtonEditor`, I'm just been lazy with my copy and pasting*

And from there, you should now be able to represent a list of `File`s in a `JTable`, where the last column is a button (with the file name) and when clicked, in this example, will print the `File` reference

## Runnable Example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new File(".").listFiles());
            FileTableModel model = new FileTableModel(files);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setDefaultEditor(File.class, new TableDeleteButtonEditor());
            table.setDefaultRenderer(File.class, new TableDeleteButtonEditor());

            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public class FileTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<File> files;

        public FileTableModel(List<File> files) {
            this.files = files;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return files.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                    return File.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            File file = files.get(row);
            switch (col) {
                case 0:
                    return file.getName();
                case 1:
                    return file;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class TableDeleteButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        private File source;
        private JButton button;

        public TableDeleteButtonEditor() {
            button = new JButton();
            button.addActionListener(new LoadActionListener());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        protected JButton prepare(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            if (!(value instanceof File)) {
                source = null;
                button.setEnabled(false);
                return null;
            }
            source = (File) value;
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setText(source.getName());
            button.setToolTipText(source.getPath());
            return button;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            return prepare(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus,
                int row,
                int column) {
            return prepare(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        }

        public class LoadActionListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // Here, you need to make some decisions about what to do...
                // You have a reference to the File instance
                System.out.println("You clicked " + source);
                stopCellEditing();
            }

        }
    }
}
```